# The Build menu theme is frozen with the wordpress theme

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

I follow [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G--9YWcH9cY).
I check my source code with [the GitHub example](https://github.com/imranhsayed/aquila) and is similar in most part.

That GitHub example theme named Aquila works on my WordPress install.

My WordPress test area is installed into localhost.

The implementation of the menu: **class-menus.php** works and the menu is shown.

The problem is the dropdown effect because the menu is frozen with the WordPress theme and not show all items menu.

If I click on the first menu button I got this:

*The requested URL was not found on this server.*

I think the problem is this part of the source code build by **nav.php** file and bootstrap files :

```
id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by freeze, sorry. Do you mean it doesn't work when you click it? Or gets stuck open once you've opened it? Or something else?

Comment: "The problem is the dropdown effect because the menu is freeze and not show all items menu." read all content.

Comment: I was asking you to explain what you mean by "is freeze". Are you not seeing all of the items because it has frozen? Or did you mean you can't see submenus because the main menu has frozen? Does the menu freeze open? Are there any script errors when it does?

Comment: I don't see the items from the menu when I go to the menu area. That is the crash point in the source code. If I click on the first menu button I got this: The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: yes ... my English translation error: freeze and frozen!